# Is there a way to make \ledsidenote behave like numbered footnotes?

Tags: reledpar

I'm making a book of parallel text with reledpar, and I would like to place the footnotes in the side margin rather than at the bottom of the page. \Ledsidenote would seem perfect for what I want, except that it doesn't seem to allow automatic note numbers the way footnotes do. In the documentation I only see options for changing which margin the notes go in. Am I missing a feature here, or is this not supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is no direct way, in the sens that reledmac has no option for that.

However, I found a way creating your own macro (which maybe, a day, I would integrate to reledmac).

### Problem 1

It was not easy, because, with parallel typesetting, reledmac reads the text not in the order it typesets it. It read all the left text, then all the right text, but typeset them alternativly. So we can't just use a normal counter to increase, because it would create trouble for the numbering of the notes when changing from left to right side.

reledpar/reledmac has an internal mechanism to deal with it (explained in the handbook), which imply to write some value in the .aux file, and then to use multiple runs in order to get the correct footnote number.

### Problem 2

A second but related problem is the fact that the time `\ledsidenote` is read by TeX and the time its content is effectivly expanded are not the same. That is linked to the way reledmac/reledpar split line for line numbering and so.

### The solution (general principle)

I will create a `\sidenoteA` macro, which will call a `\sidenoteX` macro. That allow us to deal with multiple series of side note.

The `\sidenoteX` macro will do that

1. Increase a TeX counter (`footnote#1reading`, where `#1` stand for the series letter ; this counter is already defined by reledmac)
2. From this counter, get in the auxiliary file the footnote number to typset.
3. Typeset it
4. Call `\ledsidenote`, but ensuring to get the correct `footnote#1reading` value at the sidenote is effectly typeset. Use internal macro of reledmac to get the correct footnote number to typset. Write it in auxiliary file. Deal with crossrefef mechanism. Typeset the footnote marker.

The point 4 has to deal with TeX expansion mechanism, so we have some `\edef` and `\expandafter` and `\unexpanded`.

### The code

I won't comment it directly, but you have a comment in the code itself. It call many reledmac internal macro.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[series={A},noend,noeledsec]{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\linenummargin*{inner}
% The user macro
\newcommand{\sidenoteA}[1]{%
  \sidenoteX{A}{#1}%
}
% A wrapper to be called by \sidenoteA, \sidenoteB, \sidenoteC etc
\newcommand{\sidenoteX}[2]{%
  \global\expandafter\advance\csname footnote#1@reading\endcsname by \@ne%
  \ifboolexpr{bool{l@dpairing} or bool{l@dprintingpages} or bool{l@dprintingcolumns}}{%
    \ifcsdef{footnote#1reading\the\csname footnote#1@reading\endcsname=typeset}%
    {\setcounter{footnote#1}{\csuse{footnote#1reading\the\csname footnote#1@reading\endcsname=typeset}}}%%In parallel typesetting, get the counter value from the .aux file
    {\setcounter{footnote#1}{\the\csname footnote#1@reading\endcsname}}%Fall back on first run, when .aux file is empty
  }{%
    \refstepcounter{footnote#1}%In not parallel typsetting, just increase the counter
  }%
  \protected@csxdef{@thefnmark#1}{\csuse{thefootnote#1}}%Defining the footmark value from the counter
  \csuse{@footnotemark#1}%Calling the footmark
  % A local macro to be sure to have the correct footnote number in the margin
  \edef\setthisnumber{%
    \unexpanded{\csname footnote#1@reading\endcsname}=\the\csname footnoteA@reading\endcsname%Keep the footnote reading order
    \unexpanded{\def\this@footnoteX@reading}{\the\csname footnote#1@reading\endcsname}%That is used later internally by reledmac for hyperref cross referencing
    \unexpanded{\get@thisfootnoteX{A}}%Define correctly this@cfootnote depending we are or note in parallel typesetting
    \unexpanded{\get@fnmarkX{#1}{\expandonce\thisc@footnote}{}}%Get the correct footnote number to be typeset, and save it in .aux file
    \unexpanded{\protected@edef\@currentlabel{%For cross-referencing
        \csuse{@thefnmark#1}%
      }%
      \phantomsection%For hyperref
    }%
  }
  % Now, calling sidenote macro
  \expandafter\ledsidenote\expandafter{%We need to expaend first the local macro \setthisnumber
    \setthisnumber%
    \wrapped@footfootmarkX{#1}%
    \strut#2%
  }
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \beginnumbering
      \pstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      A\sidenoteA{\label{L}The left note is written in the code before the right one, by typset after.}
      \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
      \pstart
      \label{A}A\sidenoteA{\label{R}Right is called after left note, but typeset before}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}

\end{pages}
\Pages

Crossref to L \ref{L} (p.~\pageref{L})\\
Crossref to R\ref{R} (p.~\pageref{R})\\
\end{document}
```

### Enjoy

Don't forget to use multiple run tools like `latexmk`